# SQL question - how to create date + hour dimension table?

Tags: sql, datetime

I would like to create a table showing hours 0 through 24 for each date since 1/1/2020 (until current). It would look something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFLFt.png)

Column 1: Date from 1/1/2020 until current
Column 2: Hour 0-24, repeating for each date

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Keep both date and hour as columns and use them as surrogate key to pick your rows uniquely

Comment: Btb it should be 0-23 as the Hour-Minute cycle would end in 23:59

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this using T-SQL:

```
with
tally as
(
    select top 1000 n = row_number() over(order by (select null)) - 1 from sys.messages
),
calendar as
(
    select [Date] = cast(dateadd(d, n, '1/1/2020') as date) from tally where n < datediff(d, '1/1/2020', getdate())
),
[hours] as
(
    select top 24 n from tally
)
--select * from tally;
--select * from calendar;
select [Date] = format(c.[Date], 'M/d/yyyy'), Hrs = h.n
from [hours] h
cross join calendar c
order by c.[Date], h.n;
```

The `tally` CTE creates rows with a zero based index.
The `calendar` CTE creates the dates between 1/1/2020 and today.
The `hours` CTE creates the hours from 0 through 23.
The final query creates a Cartesian Product of `calendar` and `hours`.

This is a query that generates the desired data.  If the data is to be persisted in a table, then insert logic would need to be added to the final query.